# Python 3: How to alter individual items in a list within a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function

I created a list of magician names. I am trying to add "The Great" to each individual item in the list while permanently changing the list format. Here is my code so far:

```
magician_names = ['houdini' , 'chris angel', 'ted']
def show_magicians():
    print("These are your magicians tonight.")
    while magician_names:
        print(magician_names)
        break
show_magicians()

def make_great():
    for name in magician_names:
            while True:
                ['The Great' , name]
                break
    print(magician_names)
```

I can create a for loop and a string to print each individual name with 'The Great' in front of it like so:

```
for magician in magician_names:
    print("The Great " + magician)
```

which prints this result:

```
The Great houdini
The Great chris angel
The Great ted
```

But I want it so when I call the function and print the list 'magician_names', that it prints off an altered version of the list formatted like this:

```
['the great houdini' , 'the great chris angel', 'the great ted']
```

Comment: No clue what it is you're doing exactly, but you're overcomplicating a simple problem. Lists are mutable data structures in python so all you need to do is use string concatenation with list iteration.

Comment: Replace each item in the list with the *new* string or make a new list with the new strings.

Comment: Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Comment: What's the point of  `while magician_names:
        print(magician_names)
        break` ? `print(magician_names)` does the same.

Answer (score 2):

This gives the derised output:

```
magician_names = ['houdini' , 'chris angel', 'ted']
l = ['The Great ' + name for name in magician_names]
print(l)
```

Comment: I just updated the list with that code and it works. But whenever I try and run it in a function it comes back with an error saying "local variable: 'magician_names' referenced before assignment".

Comment: @drewmende I assume that `magician_names`, is not known in that function, but it's only a guess because I have no code. Maybe you can try to pass it to function as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, I finally got it though. I put this code in the second function and when both the functions are called, the code runs back as desired.:

```
for i in range(0, len(magician_names)):
        magician_names[i] = "The Great " + magician_names[i]
```